# Mean is not calculated correctly in R?

Tags: r, average

I am struggling to understand why this happens:

```
a<-c(1.1,1.2,1.3)
b<-c(2.1,2.3,2.6)
c<-c(1.6,2.3,2.6)

mean<-rowMeans(matrix(c(a,b,c),ncol=3))  
mean  #### This are the mean values
[1] 1.600000 1.933333 2.166667

mean(a[1],b[1],c[1])  #### trying to calculate the mean of 1.1 ,2.1 and 1.6
[1] 1.1  #### Why is this not 1.6??
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

R's argument matching has caught you out:

```
> mean(9999,2,3,4,5)
[1] 9999
```

`help(mean)` says:

```
Usage:

     mean(x, ...)
```

and then says it computes the mean of `x` and passes `...` to other methods. All the numbers after 9999 in my example get captured in the dot-dot-dot.

R then calls `mean.default` because 9999 is just a number, and `mean.default` doesn't do anything with the dot-dot-dot arguments, including erroring if there's anything in them.

You can use this to add arbitrary useless things to your function calls:

```
> mean(c(1,2,3,4), monkeys=TRUE)
[1] 2.5
```

Comment: I always thought monkeys=TRUE, but didn't know for sure. Now it's confirmed.

Answer (score 5):

Your call to `mean` in `mean(a[1],b[1],c[1])` is only operating on the first element, i.e. `mean(a[1])`. You need to concatenate `a[1],b[1],c[1]` like this:

```
> mean(c(a[1],b[1],c[1]))
[1] 1.6
```

Comment: Also it's not a good idea to create an object that has the same name as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Mabye your problem is that your matrix is transposed?
Try this:

```
mean<-rowMeans(matrix(c(a,b,c),ncol=3, byrow=T))
```